# Color Icon in the Bottom Navigation Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin

**Question**

how Can I use colored icon in the Bottom `Navigation Activity`? I have a **logo** which I placed in the drawable folder but in the navigation bar its showing in black and white color instead of regular color as I copied in the drawable folder. Please share your thoughts. I am using **kotlin** language.

Comment: You can use only two colors for any icon to represent its active and inactive states if you're using Google's BottomNavigationView(most probably this is used in your activity). I'm not sure though. Try using a library or make your own bottom navigation bar

Comment: Thanks @NightMare for your information.  I am not sure why google is not allowing color icon.

Comment: They don't allow us to disable the "shift mode" too. I'll recommend using a different library like [this](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation). Use the Google version only if you're using the Navigation AAC because it has built-in integration with it

Comment: Thanks  and it looks like regular google icons.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);`. This may work. But still, I'll suggest using a different library as mentioned in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide color in `onClick` listener using

`window.navigationBarColor = Color.GREEN`

> Use Color.parseColor() to set some custom color to Navigation Bar